# my 8yrs old orange tree does not flower at all

Tags: soft-fruit

I have 2orange trees in my compound the first is about 30yrs and has been bearing fruit regularly but the second of about 8yrs has not even flowered for once what can i do

Comment: Did you purchase it commercially? Could it have been grown from seed? What kind of orange is it?

Comment: pictures would help...